How to fix Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled
Working on Arduino Cloud and i am basically trying to get the hall effect sensor to check the rpm, when it reaches a certain rpm the fan would turn off, however it crashes and i am not sure why.
Below is the error,
Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40085e08  PS      : 0x00050031  A0      : 0x8016d230  A1      : 0x3ffbf0dc
A2      : 0x00000010  A3      : 0x00018010  A4      : 0x000637ff  A5      : 0x3ffbf0ac
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x3ffbdbc8  A8      : 0x00000014  A9      : 0x4008dbf6
A10     : 0x3ffbd76c  A11     : 0x80000001  A12     : 0x00000001  A13     : 0x3ffbf08c
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000000e  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x8016d23c  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000
Backtrace:0x40085e05:0x3ffbf0dc |<-CORRUPTED
I tried rewiring and being more gentle with the wires as i thought the wires were the issue, am thinking its a code issue now.

Use backtrace decoding to get more info about what is generating the exception https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-monitor.html#automatic-address-decoding
